# Believing in Hadith

Tags: quran, hadith, authenticity

Muslims believe in the Quran, that it's the very words of Allah, and that it's Him who protect it.
Now my question is whether the Islamic hadith and, in particular, those compiled in Saih Bukhari, are also the very words of Allah. How Can we belive All the Hadith are in real form. Does Allah protect it from changing ? while Allah is says in Quran "inna Nahnu wa inna Elhe he Hafizon" Does Allah says about Hadith like Sai Bukhari ?

Comment: I've made an edit to try make sense of this question but I'm not sure I've understood it correctly.

Comment: Your question still is somewhat unclear: Do you want to know whether we should believe that sahih Hadith is also as divine as the Quran (from Allah)? Or whether it is protected? Or simply whether it has a similar level of correctness as the quran? Note that Allah has "promised" to protect the quran so it isn't really our responsibility! Please make clear what exactly you want to know then edit your question (use the edit link below your post) and ask and also check whether this isn't covered already to some extent on the site!

Comment: I want knows whether it has similar level of correctness like Quran ?

Comment: ***Does Allah says about Hadith like Sai Bukhari ?***  Shahih Bukhari is not a divine scripture and was compiled by a scholar around 230 years after the death of the Prophet.

Comment: Relevant posts https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/is-sahih-al-bukhari-considered-as-100-authentic-by-sunni-scholars, https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23/what-are-the-requirements-of-a-sahih-hadith, https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37206/what-is-the-meaning-of-hadith-grading-sahih-in-chain, https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-do-we-make-sure-if-a-hadith-is-sahih-or-fake and https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23212/which-criteria-the-rawisarabic-narrators-of-sahih-hadith-had-to-fulfil

Comment: See also https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30537/what-is-the-ruling-regarding-hadith-rejecters?, https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24773/is-the-quran-complete-if-so-why-do-we-need-hadith and https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30982/do-i-go-to-hell-for-not-believing-in-the-hadith-at-all

Answer (score 2):

Quran is Kalam of Allah, whereas, Ahadeeth are the narrations made by people mainly from the holy prophet peace be upon him and his household.
Therefore, Ahadeeth are not fully protected by Allah in the sense Quran is protected, however, there are Islamic studies on to determine which Ahadeeth are more reliable and which Ahadeeth are weaker than to be easily trusted.

Sahih Bukhari is considered as one of the most reliable hadeeth book at least for a large portion of Muslims, like Al-Kaafi is another most reliable hadeeth book for another groups of Muslims, however, all these books may have stronger or weaker Hadeeth, so that we can not easily assure if a Hadeeth is correct as we may wish.

Comment: Since so many treat hadeeths as a source of jurisprudence and to answer questions re Islam, wouldn't it be helpful if "weak" hadeeths were removed and the "strong" hadeeths kept in an abridged version of Bukhari or others, so as to avoid some of those errors?

Comment: @SKarami, the answer is both yes and no. An abridged book of Hadeeth can help, but first, determining which Hadeeth is strong never makes a single Hadeeth as authentic as Quran (at least we can almost never make sure that even the very phrases are exactly those stated by the holy prophet and his household, peace be upon them all). Second, determining a Hadeeth if is strong or weak is not a direct result of mere studying the reliability of the narrators, as the content of the Hadeeth can be vey important as well.

Comment: In one time, according to understanding of the scholars of that time, a Hadeeth may be regarded as week or not very valuable in what it says, but in another time everything might change ... Also, sometimes, scholars have different ideas about the reliability of some of the narrators, or about the authenticity of some Ahadeeth in general. Therefore, compiling an abridged Hadeeth book may depend on the personal views of the scholar/scholars that compile it ...